# Removing non digits from a form field containing a phone number

Tags: php, forms

Been searching this forum and I found what I *think* is the code to help my situation, but I am unsure how to implement it. I have a form in WHMCS (web hosting admin software) that I would like convert an entered phone number into just the digits.

For example: the end user types `(333) 444-5555`, but the form reads and records `3334445555`. I would also like to put a "1." in front of the phone number at the same time. So the final output based on input like the above would be `1.3334445555`.

My forms code (line 124): http://pastebin.com/ngMTiPbA

This is the code I found on this site that I feel may help me.

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string);
```

Can somebody help me put this together?

Comment: If you think this regex could help you why don't you try it? If you don't know what it does check out a regex tutorial or even wikipedia. This is a very simple regex shouldn't take to long to figure out what the few expressions mean.

Comment: Why assume that the 'phone number is in America? Some poor sod might end up with 'phone calls when the real person lives on the other side of the planet. Better to tell the person to type in a correct 'phone number in the first place

Comment: Please don't store phone numbers as numbers. They are not numbers. I wouldn't modify it unless you are planning automated dialling, if so remove characters before dialling.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
$phone - '1.' . preg_replace('/\D/', '', $phone);
```

The regular expression `\D` matches any non-digit.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work which you want.

```
<?php
    $str = '(333) 444-5555';
    $numbers = preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
    $numbers = implode('',$matches[0]);
    $required_output = '1.'.$numbers;
    echo $required_output; //output will be "1.3334445555"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$myPhone = "1." + (filter_var($myInpt, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
```

with this function, filter_var (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), you can sanitize variable across some specified filter (read here for more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

so if your input is

```
tel4568
```

the function returm

```
4568
```

so concatenating with "1." you have the desired string.